# How to properly set up XGBoost4J training?

Tags: xgboost

I am trying to follow the example code from [XGBoost4J](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/jvm/java_intro.html)'s tutorial, but am running into a check failure in the C++ implementation.  The error message is not obvious what's wrong:

```
ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.XGBoostError: [21:28:54] /Users/phcho/tmp/xgboost/src/objective/regression_obj.cu:35: Check failed: info.labels.Shape(0) == info.num_row_ (0 vs. 329) : Invalid shape of labels.
Stack trace:
  [bt] (0) 1   libxgboost4j3410071582095733624.dyl 0x000000013ac09a74 dmlc::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal() + 116
  [bt] (1) 2   libxgboost4j3410071582095733624.dyl 0x000000013ad495b9 xgboost::obj::(anonymous namespace)::CheckRegInputs(xgboost::MetaInfo const&, xgboost::HostDeviceVector<float> const&) + 249
  [bt] (2) 3   libxgboost4j3410071582095733624.dyl 0x000000013ad4dda8 xgboost::obj::RegLossObj<xgboost::obj::LogisticClassification>::GetGradient(xgboost::HostDeviceVector<float> const&, xgboost::MetaInfo const&, int, xgboost::HostDeviceVector<xgboost::detail::GradientPairInternal<float> >*) + 40
  [bt] (3) 4   libxgboost4j3410071582095733624.dyl 0x000000013ace6f04 xgboost::LearnerImpl::UpdateOneIter(int, std::__1::shared_ptr<xgboost::DMatrix>) + 580
  [bt] (4) 5   libxgboost4j3410071582095733624.dyl 0x000000013ac14b89 XGBoosterUpdateOneIter + 137
  [bt] (5) 6   ???                                 0x000000011671978c 0x0 + 4671510412
  [bt] (6) 7   ???                                 0x0000000116712b28 0x0 + 4671482664
  [bt] (7) 8   ???                                 0x0000000116712e90 0x0 + 4671483536
  [bt] (8) 9   ???                                 0x00000001167129ba 0x0 + 4671482298
```

The code:

```java
    List<float[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    int trainRows = (int) (rows.size() * 0.7);
    int testRows = rows.size() - trainRows;
    int columnCount = rows.get(0).length;
    float[] flatTrainMatrix = new float[trainRows * columnCount];
    float[] flatTestMatrix = new float[testRows * columnCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
      if (i < trainRows) {
        System.arraycopy(rows.get(i), 0, flatTrainMatrix, i * columnCount, columnCount);
      } else {
        System.arraycopy(rows.get(i), 0, flatTestMatrix, (i - trainRows) * columnCount, columnCount);
      }
    }
    var params = Map.<String, Object>of("max_depth", 4, "eta", 1.0, "objective", "binary:logistic", "eval_metric", "auc");
    try {
      DMatrix trainMatrix = new DMatrix(flatTrainMatrix, trainRows, columnCount, -1);
      DMatrix testMatrix = new DMatrix(flatTestMatrix, testRows, columnCount, -1);
      var booster = XGBoost.train(trainMatrix, params, 1, Map.of("train", trainMatrix, "test", testMatrix), null, null);
      booster.saveModel("/tmp/model.bin");
    } catch (XGBoostError e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);  // The error message from above is from here.  
    }
  }
```

I am using the `ml.dmlc:xgboost4j_2.12:1.6.1`.

Comment: I think you have to set labels on your train and test matrixes. So `m.setLabel(new float[]{..your Y values..})`.